# Determine if a specific triple exists using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, turtle-rdf

If the data set is:

```
@prefix dc:   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix :     <http://example.org/book/> .
@prefix ns:   <http://example.org/ns#> .

:book1  dc:title  "SPARQL Tutorial" .
:book2  dc:title  "The Semantic Web" .
```

How do I check that the triple `:book1  dc:title  "SPARQL Tutorial" .` exists?

I can do `SELECT ?book where {?book dc:title "SPARQL Tutorial"}` but then I have to do post processing to determine if 'book1' was retrieved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ASK  { ?book dc:title "SPARQL Tutorial" }
```